# Save 100000 file (1MB file) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008

I have idea to create an application in C# to save files like `pdf`, `doc`, image on server and I have SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

Can I save 100'000 files (of 1MB size each) in the database yearly?

So that I need to get me disadvantages and is the database become slow

Comment: _File_ systems are good at saving files, _data_ bases are good at saving data. Take it from there.

Comment: You *can* - technically - but that still doesn't necessarily means that it's a *good idea* .....

Comment: I'd probably use `FILESTREAM` if I *had* to store these files in the DB, then you get both worlds.

Comment: The main disadvantage is that management access is harder - i.e. if you want to browse, open, or copy some files. You have to create your own tool (file manager).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a really good paper by Microsoft Research called [To Blob or Not To Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525).

Their conclusion after a large number of performance tests and analysis is this:

- if your pictures or document are typically below 256K in size, storing them in a database's `VARBINARY` column is more efficient
- if your pictures or document are typically over 1 MB in size, storing them in the filesystem is more efficient (and with SQL Server 2008's `FILESTREAM` attribute, they're still under transactional control and part of the database)
- in between those two, it's a bit of a toss-up depending on your use

For filegroups, check out [Files and Filegroup Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx) for an intro. Basically, you would either create your database with a separate filegroup for large data structures right from the beginning, or add an additional filegroup later. Let's call it `LARGE_DATA`.

Now, whenever you have a new table to create which needs to store `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `VARBINARY(MAX)` columns, you can specify this file group for the large data:

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
 (....... define the columns here ......)
 ON Data                   -- the basic "Data" filegroup for the regular data
 TEXTIMAGE_ON LARGE_DATA   -- the filegroup for large chunks of data
```

Check out the MSDN intro on filegroups, and play around with it!